# Find the equations of trajectories for the system of ODE and find which are closed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following system:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=y-1$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-xy$

We now want to find a differential equation for the trajectories and to solve that equation, and to find a differential equation for the trajectories I did the following:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy}{y-1}$ and I tried to solve this i got the following:

$y-\ln(y)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1$

They now ask me to determine which trajectories are closed. I don't know how to do this can anyone help me?

Comment: Actually, the trajectories are the level lines $$y-\ln|y|=-\tfrac12x^2+c$$ The function $g(y)=ye^{-y}$ is such that $g(y)=h$ has two solutions if $0<h<e^{-1}$, one solution if $h\leqslant0$ or $h=e^{-1}$, and zero solution if $h>e^{-1}$. Thus, the closed orbits are $$C(y_0)=\{(x,y)\mid g(y)=g(y_0)e^{x^2/2}\}$$ for every $$y_0>0$$ If $y_1<1<y_2$ are such $$g(y_1)=g(y_2)$$ then $C(y_1)=C(y_2)$ is a topological circle passing by the points $(0,y_1)$ and $(0,y_2)$. The degenerate orbit $C(1)$ is reduced to the fixed point $(0,1)$. Finally, $$\bigcup_{y_0\in(0,1]}C(y_0)=\{(x,y)\mid y>0\}$$